# The position of an object

Tags: phrase-request

When we wear something with the part that is usually inside facing out, we say:

**inside out**

> You've got your sweater on inside out.

When something faces to the ground we say:

*upside down.*

What do we say when an object is placed in its usual position?

For instance, there is a shoe with its upside towards the ground, we'll say:

> The shoe is lying upside down.

What would we say for the following picture?

[image]

> The shoe is placed upright.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you don't need to mention it.

> The shoe is on the floor (implies the usual position)

If it is necessary you can "right way up".

> Put the box down the right way up, or you might damage the contents.

It is also possible to use "not"

> Do not put your jumper on inside out, it will be uncomfortable.

"Upright" might work in some cases, but to me that suggests "with the sole vertical. (Leave your shoes upright against the wall and they will dry quicker)